# Problem with Objective-C for loop

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, for-loop

I have two methods, the generateRandomCard method gets called within the testMethod, where there is a for loop that runs 100 times. That way it works perfect, but if I set the for loop limit to 1000 or any other number greater than 100 it crashes. Can you see what's wrong??

```
- (void)testMethod {

    Globals *myGlobals = [Globals sharedInstance];
    int rankOfFirst = 0;
    int rankOfSecond = 0;
    int playerOneWin = 0;
    int playerTwoWin = 0;
    int ties = 0;
    float firstPercent = 0;
    float secondPercent = 0;
    float tiePercent = 0;
    FiveEval *evaluator = [FiveEval theEvaluator];

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        short fPF = [self generateRandomCard];
        short fPS = [self generateRandomCard];
        short sPF = [self generateRandomCard];
        short sPS = [self generateRandomCard];
        short fFlop = [self generateRandomCard];
        short sFlop = [self generateRandomCard];
        short tFlop = [self generateRandomCard];
        short tur = [self generateRandomCard];
        short riv = [self generateRandomCard];

        rankOfFirst = [evaluator getRankOfSeven:fFlop 
                                               :sFlop 
                                               :tFlop
                                               :tur 
                                               :riv 
                                               :fPF 
                                               :fPS];

        rankOfSecond = [evaluator getRankOfSeven:fFlop 
                                             :sFlop 
                                             :tFlop 
                                             :tur 
                                             :riv 
                                             :sPF 
                                             :sPS];

        if (rankOfFirst > rankOfSecond) {
            playerOneWin++;
        } else if (rankOfSecond > rankOfFirst) {
            playerTwoWin++;
        } else {
            ties++;
        }

        [myGlobals.alreadyPickedCards removeAllObjects];
    }

    firstPercent = ((float)playerOneWin/(float)10000)*100;
    secondPercent = ((float)playerTwoWin/(float)10000)*100;
    tiePercent = ((float)ties/(float)10000)*100;

    NSLog(@"First Player Equity: %f", firstPercent);
    NSLog(@"Second Player Equity: %f", secondPercent);
    NSLog(@"Tie Equity: %f", tiePercent);
}


- (short)generateRandomCard {

    Globals *myGlobals = [Globals sharedInstance];
    short i = arc4random()%51;
    for (int j = 0; j < [myGlobals.alreadyPickedCards count]; j++) {
        if (i == [[myGlobals.alreadyPickedCards objectAtIndex:j] shortValue]) {
            [self generateRandomCard];
        }
    }
    [myGlobals.alreadyPickedCards addObject:[NSNumber numberWithShort:i]];
    return i;
}
```

Comment: What's the error message you're getting?

Comment: In what way does it crash?  What does the log say?

Comment: The log says nothing, but it highlights the following line of code in the generateRandomCard method: "if (i == [[myGlobals.alreadyPickedCards objectAtIndex:j] shortValue])" and it says: Program received signal: "EXC_BAD_ACCESS".

Comment: Could you shows us how you create the singleton? Also, retain theEvaluator and release it at the end of your -testMethod

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably [overflowing your stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow) in the recursive call to `-generateRandomCard`.  If you generate a card that's already been picked, you call yourself recursively (and ignore the result, which is a different bug).  So, if your random number stream gave you an unlucky sequence that kept returning cards you've already picked, then you'll recurse infinitely until the stack overflows.

Change your card selection algorithm so that instead of using [rejection sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling) with the potential for infinite looping/recursion, it uses an algorithm with a bounded runtime such as the [Fisher-Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle).

Comment: Awesome stack overflow (unintended) pun. +1 for the selection algorithm tho.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this could in any way lead to the crash - It may be unrelated. However, it does look like you have a bug in the way you recursively call generateRandomCard when a card is found in the alreadyPickedCards array. Instead of

```
[self generateRandomCard];
```

I think you should have

```
return [self generateRandomCard];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have in -testMethod: 
`[myGlobals.alreadyPickedCards removeAllObjects];`

and in -generateRandomCard you have:

```
for (int j = 0; j < [myGlobals.alreadyPickedCards count]; j++) {
    if (i == [[myGlobals.alreadyPickedCards objectAtIndex:j] shortValue]) {
        [self generateRandomCard];
    }
}
```

I can't bet for sure, but this looks like a situation where you removeAllObjects in 1 loop and access an out of bound index in another loop.

If you wanna play like this with arrays, I suggest you make copies of arrays and remove items from those copied arrays.

Comment: While that's a valid concern, I don't think that's what's going on here -- the `-count` method gets called at every loop iteration, so even if the array size did change, the index would never become out of bounds.  Also, accessing an `NSArray` out of bounds results an in `NSRangeException` being thrown, not an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` signal.

Comment: exactly, I don't think that's the problem here.